is there an existing way or tool to convert user actions on a UI into a Prolog program?
I'm still in the design process, and I would like to know if there is a way to transform user input in a UI (in the form of a JSON object) into a Prolog program ?
The point is to verify compliance of whatever the user defined in terms of the system components and the properties that must hold true.
I would prefer to use some well-established and tested way if it exists.
I did some research on the internet, I also tried some AI tools, but I still can't find a relatively quick way to do this. I would prefer to use some well-established  and tested way if it exists
